# get() HTML from a file - loading it into text editor doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, function

The problem is that the initial load with load(); works okay, but when I try to call the same function with a button click it doesn't fill my textarea.

```
$("#save").click(function () {
$("#save").html("Loading"); 
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "input.php",
data: dataString,
cache: true,
success: function(html){
$("#save").html("Save"); 
load();
} 
});
});

function load() {
    $.get("textfile.html", function(content) { 
        $("#active").html(content); 
    });
};

load();

$(".button").click(function() {
    load();
});
```

and the html

```
<a class="button" style="">Button</a>
<textarea id="active" style="width: 100%; height: 500px; margin: 20px auto;"></textarea>
<a id="save" style="">Save</a>
```

I have now changed it to this:

```
tinymce.get('activeta').setContent(content);
```

The problem is that now I don't see a changed content when i click save, but the initial content in the editor parsed by load()..

Comment: please post html too

Comment: What you have should work fine, although you can cut it down to just call jQuery's `load()` method. Are you sure the `.button` element is raising the click event? Is it appended to the DOM after load?

Comment: Yes it's editable textarea.. Button click works, because I tried with an alert, even when I try to test the load function and add alert there it shows up, but the textarea isn't filled..

Comment: You likely activate the editor AFTER the inline `load()` but then it is no longer a textarea and in the button you need setContent

Comment: @mlupngjan Please see the updated code.. The problem I have now is that the updated file is not shown after saving it..